# How to reinstall WordPress site using only a backup folder of it?

Tags: wordpress

My old WordPress site's host is not accessible so I decided to copy the WordPress folder out as a backup hoping to recreate this into another host.

The question is how can I make this WordPress site up and running again in another host? I only have the folder but if anything is needed more than that, I will try to get it out from the old host if possible.

I tried searching but there seems to be either migrating using import/export or using plugins. I cannot get everything from the old host, only some.

Comment: If you have WordPress foldder of existing site. Half of your work is done. 
you need database of existing site too In order to have the old data. 

Once you have these two things you can easily do the wordpress migration or take hosting support help.

Comment: @NaveenGiri How can I export the database when I cannot access the web dashboard?

Comment: If you still have access to your hosting or Cpanel. You can do it from there.
If you do not have cpanel access of your previous hosting. you can talk to hosting support guys there. 

otherwise if you have any old backup of your website DB. 
maybe possible your developer have that.

Comment: If all above things not goes good, Finger crossed. You lost old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important in your wordpress it's the database.
You must export your database, with phpadmin or other.

then you must change all occurences of the old host by the new.

If the wordpress is no longer accessible you must find where is store your database.
For this, you must look in the wp-config file at the root of wordpress project.
In this file :

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

With this informations you can connect to the database.

If the DB_HOST refers to a phpmyadmin website you can export the database with [this](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin)

[For more informations](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: The old site (web dashboard) is not accessible anymore. Please explain in details how to export the database from a host where the web dashboard is not accessible.

Comment: @holydragon You can choose my answer as the good one ? so that other users can enjoy it ? thank you

Comment: Your answer did not entirely solve my problem but it is helpful nonetheless. So, I will give it to you but not for the sake of user enjoyment.

Answer (score 2):

You say, no more Dashboard access. But maybe you are lucky and you still got FTP access. in this case you could upload a database tool like [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/de/) , configure it with the data you find in wp-config.php and export the database from Adminer.

Also, are you sure you dont have a backup-folder in your wp-content / uploads Folder? If you had a backup-tool installed, you will find the .sql file in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to access the site database then you won't be able to copy any content from the old site.  All the content is in your database.

The best you can do is to reinstall WP with a fresh database then copy over your theme file from your backup (wp-content > themes) and any plugins your site uses (wp-content > plugins) then activate them all.  You'll have a site with the same theme, styling and functionality but will have to start again with creating pages and content.

You may also be able to save any images etc. that you've uploaded to the site by copying them from wp-content > uploads.  Files you upload are the only part of your content that is held on the server and not in the database.